# Why add state value to variable before return within render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I often see the following pattern used within JavaScript classes and React.

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  state: {
   someValue: 1
  }

  render() {
    const myValue = this.state.someValue;

    return <h1>Hello, {myValue}</h1>;
  }
}
```

My question is, what is the point/benefit of declaring state to a variable before the return when you can access the value with `this.state.someValue` within return anyway?

Comment: It is mainly used for destructuring .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of assigning to a variable or destructuring comes when you are using the same variable multiple times you multiple variables from array in which case you don't need to write `this.state` again and again.

In the above case you could simply use the value from state and there isn't any benefit to assignment before using.